# conda install tensorflow-gpu vs conda install keras-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conda

What is the functional difference between:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

and

```
conda install keras-gpu
```

I created a conda environment and only used the conda install tensorflow-gpu command and now to import anything from the keras module in that environment, I have to write tensorflow.keras instead of keras.

If I use conda install keras-gpu, will I be able to use keras without the tensorflow reference? If so, are there any other differences between the two installations?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47759/keras-vs-tf-keras